# IGBT VCEsat maximum rating dependence on VGE

Tags: igbt

Building an application with IGBTs up to 1000V and using IXGA20N120A3 rated at 1200V. However datasheet states that this rating is for a Vge = 0V. We are driving the IGBT with -12V during turn off to avoid self turn on and was wandering if the maximum VCE might be lower due to this negative Vge.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max volt rating is lower by only 12 V .This should not matter when normal safety factors are applied.